# How to compare multiple rows of the same column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to compare multiple rows of the same column in the same table and display one single value using SQL query. I want to display just a single row with value 1 if Accepted=Accepted and display 0 if Accepted<>Accepted.

**Table I have**

Table name - work

| status |
| --- |
| Accepted |
| Declined |

**Desired output**

| status |
| --- |
| 0 |

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement? Do you want `status` to be `0` if any row in that column is `Declined` and `status` to be `1` if every rows has `Accepted` in the status column?

Comment: As @GregPavlik mentionned, what's the purpose ? You only want to have Accepted values ? There's many ways to perform such results, but we need to have more information about what you really need ! :-)